# Are there any XAML functions that can derive a color from a base color?

Tags: css, wpf, xaml, javafx, fxml

JavaFX has a CSS function : `derive(color, %)`. This lets you say something like `derive(red, 50%)` to get a color that is 50% lighter than the base color, Red, or `derive(red, -50%)`

Does XAML have something equivalent function for manipulating colors?

Answer (score 0):

You can Change the color by any of Microsoft WPF editors like blend for Visual Studio 2013 or 2012 or you can change by properties of visual studio or by code by in c# color rgb you can change the amount of color .....etc

Comment: yes, but i want to do it in code, for the purpose of styling, rather than hard-coding. for example, if i have a template based off the color 'red', i want to be able to pass the color of the template in and be able to say "Derive(Color, Percent)".

Comment: byte r = this.o_brush.Color.R;
            byte g = this.o_brush.Color.G;
            byte b = this.o_brush.Color.B;
            byte alpha = this.o_brush.Color.A;
            alpha += (byte)color_delta;
            if (alpha >= 240 || alpha <= 1)
                color_delta *= -1;
            this.o_brush = new SolidColorBrush(
                Color.FromArgb(alpha, r, g, b));
            this.o_shape.Fill = this.o_brush;

Comment: Thank you, but how do I call it from the XAML code?

Comment: @Will you need a MarkupExtension for that. I'm preparing a sample to demonstrate how to do this in a clean, reusable, XAML enabled manner.

Comment: i doesn`t know because i do it by editor you can try it by editor and see the change of Xaml if you want to do it in c# code an call in xaml you should make it {binding }

Comment: @HighCore Thanks. I have a method that I think will suit my purposes for adjusting a color, I just need to figure out how to use it in XAML.

Comment: @Will you can use an `IValueConverter` for that. That's a simple quick solution, however the usage syntax is not optimal. I'm looking for a way to implement that via a MarkupExtension that provides a much cleaner syntax